# WorkManager progress not propagated

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

I'm trying to listen to my worker to know when he is done:

```kotlin
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val collectionName = checkNotNull(inputData.getString(COLLECTION_NAME_KEY))
        val uris = checkNotNull(inputData.getStringArray(URIS_KEY)?.toList()?.map { Uri.parse(it) })

        setForegroundAsync(createForegroundInfo())

        val collectionId = Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextLong()
        val comics = saveFileAndCreateComics(collectionId, uris)
        val collection = ComicCollection(id = collectionId, name = collectionName)

        database.comicCollectionDao().insert(collection, comics)

        setProgress(workDataOf(IMPORT_FINISHED to true)) <-- propagate event

        Result.success()
    }
```

To observe event:

```kotlin
        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)

        val data = Data.Builder()
            .putString(ImportFilesWorker.COLLECTION_NAME_KEY, collectionName)
            .putStringArray(ImportFilesWorker.URIS_KEY, uris.map { it.toString() }.toTypedArray())
            .build()

        val uploadWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<ImportFilesWorker>()
            .setInputData(data)
            .setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.RUN_AS_NON_EXPEDITED_WORK_REQUEST)
            .build()

        workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(WORK_NAME, ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, uploadWorkRequest)

        WorkManager.getInstance(context)
            .getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(uploadWorkRequest.id)
            .observeForever { workInfo ->
                workInfo?.progress?.let {
                    val finished = it.getBoolean(IMPORT_FINISHED, false) <-- listen event
                    Timber.e("FINISHED = $finished")
                }
            }
```

But from the log I always get `FINISHED = false`. What am I missing here?

**Update:**
If I also log the `WorkInfo` state I got the following in the logcat:

```
STATE = ENQUEUED
FINISHED = false
STATE = RUNNING
FINISHED = false
STATE = SUCCEEDED
FINISHED = false
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not just observing the `state` of the work request to see if it is finished? Either one of the finished states or `WorkInfo.State.isFinished()`

Comment: In the end I will probably follow this path but I also would like to understand why my code does not work (while it should)...

Comment: I found it useful to always log the `state` when observing anything because I think sometimes you can get in to a pickle with Unique work because of "The existing work becomes a prerequisite to the new work. If the existing work becomes CANCELLED or FAILED, the new work is also CANCELLED or FAILED"

Comment: @Andrew I've updated my answer with the logs. It still does not make sense that I got a succeeded state while `FINISHED` is still false...